# How to deal with External authentication for already existing local user or new user

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-identity

I using ASP.Net Core 3 Identity with Identity Server 4 for authentication ...

On the AspNetIdentity template the External Authentication Controller Callback method calls the [AutoProvisionUserAsync](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L178) method which has the following code:

```
  var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Email)?.Value ??
     claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
  if (email != null) {
    filtered.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, email));
  }

  var user = new User {
    UserName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
  };

  var identityResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

Basically it creates a user with a Guid as Username ...

In my database I am using Email as Username ... Is there any reason to use a Guid?

I suppose most External authentication services (Google, Facebook, etc) provides an Email.

So my idea would be:

1. Check if there is an User in the database already with that email.
2. If no User exists create one with the email obtained from the External authentication service.
   Also add the external authentication to the User in the database;
3. If there is a User with the email in the database check if it has that External Login.
   If the user does not have the external login register and add it.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Check if there is an User in the database already with that email.

On callback, first call is to [FindUserFromExternalProviderAsync](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L153), it search users using nameIdentifier, then if not found there is call to [AutoProvisionUserAsync](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L178)

> Basically it creates a user with a Guid as Username ...
> In my database I am using Email as Username ... Is there any reason to use a Guid?

The [ApplicationUser](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4AspNetIdentity/Models/ApplicationUser.cs)'s base class is [IdentityUser](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs), IdentityUser has a prop for ID and one for email by design. thats why most of libraries take advantage of having GUID as ID in addition of email for extensibility. You can use the email for ID if you like to.

Comment: I was not considering using email as id but an int as id. Would be better to user a Guid as id?

Comment: Im not sure what is your question? Do you mean if having int is better than guid? If this is ur question, its ok to do so, you can implement a custom ApplicationUser for it.

Comment: I usually use INT (auto increment) in all entities IDs including User. However ASP.NET Core 3 Identity uses String type as ID and populates it as a Guid. I was wondering if there is any "hidden" reason for that related to external authentication? I really don't see many advantages of using Guid besides: 1. Easier tables merge between databases; 2. Ability to create the ID without calling the database.

Comment: On ASP.NET there is also generic class for IdentityUser which you can have any type for ID:  https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs#L42  IdSvr4 uses the IdentityUser with string ID as base, but you can customize the ApplicationUser as mentioned above

Comment: About pros and cons of GUID I can add some more to ur items such as: 1. GUID is unique across tables, databases and servers 2. simplifies distribution of databases across multiple servers 3. most replication scenarios require GUID columns - but at the end of day it all depends to ur requirements - here is a good post to read about it https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/

Comment: I am also confused as the author of this post. Why in the definition of the class JwtClaimTypes.cs https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/94c5fb61bfeb3389846801a380e74575eb78e287/src/JwtClaimTypes.cs#L43 the comment states that "The relying party MUST NOT rely upon this value being unique" ? isn't email address unique also across providers?